# Yup .mixed() not working with sibling child

Tags: javascript, validation, formik, yup

My data structure looks like this:

```
{
  foo: true,
  bar: {
    baz: [{label: 'mario', url: 'https://nintendo.com'}]
  }
}
```

And my `yup` validator looks like this:

```
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    foo: yup.boolean(),
    bar: yup.mixed().when('foo', {
      is: true,
      then: yup.object().shape({
        baz: yup.array.of(
          yup.object().shape({
            label: yup.string.required(),
            url: yup.url().required()
          })
        )
      }),
      otherwise: yup.object().nullable(true)
    })
  })
```

But the validation isn't working for `bar.baz`; if `foo` is `true`, bar never throws an error if it isn't given an array with the required objects.

If I set `bar` to validate as something else, say:

```
  bar: yup.mixed().when('foo', {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required()
    otherwise: yup.string.nullable(true)
  })
```

It throws an error for `bar` as expected.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when()` only has access to properties at the same level. From [the documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema):

> **mixed.when(keys: string | Array, builder: object | (value, schema)=> Schema): Schema**
>
> Adjust the schema based on a sibling or sibling children fields. You can provide an object literal where the key is is value or a matcher function, then provides the true schema and/or otherwise for the failure condition.

That's why your second example works (because `bar` and `foo` are siblings). One possible solution is to rearrange your data so that `foo` and `baz` are siblings.

There is at least [one issue on Yup's Github](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/398) and the author suggests passing data is through Yup's context parameter but I don't think that is possible using Formik and the `validationSchema` prop, assuming that's what you're using.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I suspected, as well.  Good to know it's been confirmed.